# Can Alerts be customized?

Tags: templates, dispatch, alerts

Is there a way to edit the information included in different Alerts? For instance, if something doesn't include Job # and the customer needs to be able to have Job # in all alerts in order to be able to connect the dots, I would like to know if there is a way to change around what information is available.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some of the alerts can be altered via configs. They have placeholders that can be changed (though there are only certain available placeholders.

If you hover over the internal note it will show you the available placeholders for that template.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHSIb.png)

Search template with Ctrl+F and you should see the ones that appear.